# Get literal system variable path

Tags: c#, path, environment-variables, path-variables, raw-data

Is there any way to get the path environmental variable as a literal string instead of expanded?

i.e.

`%systemroot%\System32;%systemroot%\;etc...`

instead of

`C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows\;etc...`

I've tried using

```
Environment.GetSystemVariable("Path");
```

But that gives me the expanded directories and I don't see anything else under Environment that will get me that.

Edit:

`PathUnExpandEnvStrings` only works if the entire path is an environmental variable.

i.e.

`C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;etc...`

becomes

`C:\Windows\System32;%systemroot%;etc...`

using

`Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment", "Path", null);`

Still gets the values as `C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;etc...`

Comment: Why do you want the environment variable instead of the actual path?

Comment: [PathUnExpandEnvStrings](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi/PathUnExpandEnvStrings.html) via PInvoke?

Comment: You could read it directly from the system registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` where there is a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value called `Path`

Comment: @Amy I'm trying to append a directory to the current path.

Comment: @stuartd PathUnExpandEnvStrings only works if the entire string matches an environmental variable, i.e. C:\Windows\System32 doesn't get unexpanded only C:\Windows does.

Comment: @Jeffrey By "current path", do you mean the PATH environment variable?

Comment: @Wyck This still expands the directories.

Comment: @Amy yes, the PATH environmental variable

Comment: What's preventing you from appending a directory to `C:\Windows\System32`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the registry route you can pass [`RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvalueoptions) to the [`RegistryKey.GetValue()` instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue) to get the unexpanded path...

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace SO60725684
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            const string environmentKeyPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";
            const string valueName = "TEMP";

            using (RegistryKey environmentKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(environmentKeyPath))
            {
                foreach (RegistryValueOptions options in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RegistryValueOptions)))
                {
                    object valueData = environmentKey.GetValue(valueName, "<default>", options);

                    Console.WriteLine($"{valueName} ({options}) = \"{valueData}\"");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints...

```
Temp (None) = "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP"
Temp (DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames) = "%SystemRoot%\TEMP"
```

I'm using the `"TEMP"` variable just for the brevity of its value, but it works just as well for `"Path"`.

If you don't want to rely on the backing storage of an environment variable, there is also a [`Win32_Environment` management class](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-environment) that exposes the value without expansion...

```cs
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace SO60725684
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] propertiesToDisplay = new string[] { "Name", "SystemVariable", "UserName", "VariableValue" };
            ObjectQuery query = new SelectQuery("Win32_Environment", "Name = 'TEMP'", propertiesToDisplay);

            using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query))
            using (ManagementObjectCollection resultCollection = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (ManagementBaseObject resultInstance in resultCollection)
                {
                    PropertyDataCollection properties = resultInstance.Properties;

                    foreach (string propertyName in propertiesToDisplay)
                    {
                        PropertyData property = properties[propertyName];

                        Console.WriteLine($"{property.Name}: {property.Value}");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This prints...

```
Name: TEMP
SystemVariable: True
UserName: <SYSTEM>
VariableValue: %SystemRoot%\TEMP

Name: TEMP
SystemVariable: False
UserName: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
VariableValue: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

Name: TEMP
SystemVariable: False
UserName: ComputerName\UserName
VariableValue: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

As you can see, you get multiple results when the variable is defined for multiple users, so you'll need to do further filtering on the `SystemVariable` and `UserName` properties to get the one you want.

Comment: @Jeffrey I have updated my answer with a `System.Management` alternative as well.  If you need a `PathUnExpandEnvStrings`-like solution that works on partial paths, I recently posted [this PowerShell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60090703/150605) that attempts to unexpand arbitrary paths using a set of environment variable paths.  Hopefully that's readily readable/translatable for C#.